# Error while creating a dynamic table only last row information is shown and that too in the first row

Tags: android, dynamic, layout-inflater

I want to create a dynamic table.

Here table1row is a layout having one row and I want to intialize its content and add it each time to a table layout to generate the table but I am getting an output like:

```
column3

TextView2

TextView3
```

instead of:

```
column1

column2

column3
```

ColumnMetaInfo is used to get the data I have checked and I am receiving the data properly but for the first iteration while setting TextView column_name an exception is thrown and for the rest two iteration it sets the value but in the output only last value is shown and that too at the first row:

```
for (int j = 0; j <3 ; j++) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table1row, null, false);
        column_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.col_name);
        ColumnMetaInfo colInfo = colInfoList.get(j);

        if (colInfo.getColName() != null) {
            String n = colInfo.getColName().toString();
            try{
            column_name.setText(n);
            }
            catch(Exception e){ 
            }
        }
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
}
```

table1row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/table1_row"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/col_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: You are inflating a `TextView`. So you will obviously view `TextView`. Your output is unclear. Please provide screenshots or more detailed information

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem but I solved it the problem was I should have intialized column_name using row.findViewById(...) instead of just findViewById